# How to produce a header row in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

In log4j, we sometimes create a second logger and output CSV data to it as sort of a metrics watch of the application.  This data is easily imported and graphed, as opposed to the normal log which we use for debugging and the like.

In old log4j we did this by subclassing the PatternLayout, overriding the header property, and specifying it as:

```
log4j.logger.servicePerformance=INFO, servicePerformance
log4j.appender.servicePerformance=mypackage.log4j.SingleHeaderFileAppender
log4j.appender.servicePerformance.File=logs/performance.log
log4j.appender.servicePerformance.layout=mypackage.log4j.HeaderLayout
log4j.appender.servicePerformance.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.servicePerformance.layout.Header=Start Time, Service Invoked, Elapsed ms, Candidate Count, Asset Count
log4j.additivity.servicePerformance=false
```

I'm not sure how to do this in log4j 2 which we now have two applications recently converted to use.

Answer (score 7):

Log4j2's PatternLayout also supports the header and footer attributes:

```
<PatternLayout>
  <pattern>%d %p [%t] %c %m%n</pattern>
  <header>This is a header</header>
  <footer>(c) 1999-2014</footer>
</PatternLayout>
```

I think attributes work too:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%t] %c %m%n"
  header="This is a header"
  footer="(c) 1999-2014" />
```

This is not documented correctly, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I REALLY wish this was true.  But it is not.  I added: <header>Function, Start Time, Elapsed MS, Assets Requested, Assets Returned</header> and got: 2014-07-07 09:42:21,704 ERROR PatternLayout contains an invalid element or attribute "header"

Comment: Which version of log4j2 are you using? rc2?

Comment: Header/footer support was added in log4j2-rc2 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-496 ).

Comment: It is still an issue in that the proposed solution puts the header out everytime the app starts or stops, not just on new file.

Comment: Progress, good! :-) How about setting append="false" on the appender?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution, I am also stuck on this.

Comment: @Tomer What version of Log4j2 are you using?

Comment: Hi @RemkoPopma, How can I check this?

Comment: Look at the jar file names or the Maven dependency version number.

Comment: Hi, Thnx. The version is 1.2.17

Comment: Ok, thanks. My advice is to upgrade to 2.8.2. You'll need both the log4j-api and the log4j-core jars. For applications coded against the old log4j 1.2 API, also include the log4j-1.2-api adapter. After that you can use a Log4j2 configuration with headers and footers.

Comment: Thanks!
Is it possible with out upgrading? The reason why I ask is since I am writing on the core code of the company code. Therefor if I upgrade "log4j" it might do problems in the company.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Are you aware that Log4j 1.2 has been End of Life since August 2015? (https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces). Also, Log4j 1.2 is known to be broken in Java 9 (https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/moving_on_to_log4j_2). If  your company code is simply logging and not trying to customize Log4j 1.2 then the log4j-1.2-api adapter should make migration easy.