# How to write custom header in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to write the custom header row at the start of the log file. The custom header is **Date/Time, XML filename, <treatydoc or <amendingdoc, Message**. 
In **log4j**, I can create a custom header by extending PatternLayout.
 I have included the log4j properties config and child class **CustomFileHeaderLayout** of PatternLayout for the custom header. It works fine.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, R1, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.ibfd.addmliednotes.util.CustomFileHeaderLayout
##org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{dd MMM hh:mm:ss aa}] - %m%n
log4j.appender.R1=org.ibfd.addmliednotes.util.CustomFileAppender
##org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R1.File=${file.name}
log4j.appender.R1.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R1.layout=org.ibfd.addmliednotes.util.CustomFileHeaderLayout
log4j.appender.R1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd MMM hh:mm:ss aa}] %m%n
```

**CustomFileHeaderLayout.java**

```
public class CustomFileHeaderLayout extends PatternLayout{  
    public String getHeader(){  
        return "Date/Time, XML filename, <treatydoc or <amendingdoc, Message\r\n";
    } 
}
```

However, I'm unable to do this in **log4j2**, as log4j2's PatternLayout declared as the final class and does not provide the getHeader() method also. I'm not sure how to do this in log4j2.

Comment: The question was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553348/how-to-produce-a-header-row-in-log4j2

Answer (score 0):

i've add some extras to my log4j2 patterns...  like environment variables, or context variables... i hope it helps for you

pattern = [%X{global}] | [$${env:RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT}] | [%level] | [%logger{15}] | [Method:%M Line:%L %msg]%n

RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT is set user profile, or command line with set or export ...
global is set using log4j2 context with org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext (ThreadContext.put("global", "anything"))

Take a look to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html